# THREE.js CylinderGeometry.attributes not defined

Tags: javascript, three.js, threejs-editor

I am having trouble accessing the .attributes.position for any sort of geometry in THREE.js. Basically, the console error is 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'position')'.

```
const cylinderGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5, 5, 5, 5, 15, 5, 30 );
const position = cylinderGeometry.attributes.position;
const vertex = new THREE.Vector3();
```

For reference, the snippet is taken from https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/SkinnedMesh.

Any idea why this might happen? Could it be related to the THREE.js version I am using?

Comment: if you're using version before r125, then `CylinderGeometry` is `Geometry`, not `BufferGeometry`. Try to use `CylinderBufferGeometry`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Three.js version r125 or later, you should be able to get the position attribute of any geometry [with the `.getAttribute()` method.](https://threejs.org/docs/?q=geometry#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.getAttribute):

```js
const cylinderGeometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry( 5, 5, 5, 5, 15, 5, 30 );
const posAttribute = cylinderGeometry.getAttribute("position");
const posArray = posAttribute.array;
```

If you're using version r124 or earlier, then the Geometry generated used to be structured differently. This approach is now deprecated, so it's recommended you update to a newer version.